# add words to sharepoint online spell dictionary

Tags: sharepoint-online, spellchecker

we have a hosted instances of SharePoint 2013 in sharepoint online (office 365)

how can we add words to the spell check dictionary. our company name still comes up as misspelled and its driving us all crazy

Answer (score 2):

1. You can create a document library at the root site level and call it "Spelling".
2. Put a file there called Custom Dictionary.txt.  Add a few words to this .txt file and these words now will be included in your custom dictionary.

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

I think, the file name has to be exactly "Custom Dictionary.txt". Otherwise it might not work.