# Customized Spell Checking

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, spellchecker

My users do not like the way the spell checking works in SP.

They basically want the Microsoft Word experience where they right click on a word and can automatically add it to a list.

While I imagine this could be coded, I'd rather than create something OOTB that I imagine would exist that I could purchase.

Does anyone either have any recommendations to easily do this behavior or something to purchase to handle the interface similar to the way its handled in MS Word?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot achieve your requirement directly.

There is a workaround.

We can create a document library named “Spelling”. And create a new text file called "Custom Dictionary".

Then add the words you would like NOT to be considered misspelled words into the "Custom Dictionary.txt".

Then upload the "Custom Dictionary.txt" to the “Spelling” document library.
After all, the words specified in the "Custom Dictionary" file will not be considered as spelling errors.

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Add spell check dictionary in SharePoint 2010, SharePoint 2013, and Office 365.](http://rwcchen.blogspot.com/2016/10/add-spell-check-dictionary-in.html)

there is a similar post:

[add words to sharepoint online spell dictionary](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/106088/add-words-to-sharepoint-online-spell-dictionary)

Comment: This is the OOTB functionality I mention above that the users don't like...im looking for alternatives to that